# How to Apply String Vector to Logical Vector

Tags: r

I would like to replace any instances of `TRUE` in a logical vector with the corresponding elements of a same-lengthed string vector.

For example, I would like to combine:

```
my_logical <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
my_string <- c("A", "B", "C")
```

to produce:

```
c("A", "", "C")
```

I know that:

```
my_string[my_logical]
```

gives:

```
"A" "C"
```

but can't seem to figure out how to return a same-lengthed vector. My first thought was to simply multiply the vectors together, but that raises the error "non-numeric argument to binary operator."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
my_logical <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
my_string <- c("A", "B", "C")
my_replace <- ifelse(my_logical==TRUE,my_string,'')
my_replace
[1] "A" ""  "C"
```

Edit, thanks @www:

```
ifelse(my_logical, my_string, "")
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option with `replace`

```
replace(my_string, !my_logical, "")
#[1] "A" ""  "C"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ifelse` to add `NA` when `my_logical` equals `FALSE` (`TRUE` otherwise). Use this to subset.

```
new <- my_string[ifelse(!my_logical, NA, T)]
new

[1] "A" NA  "C"
```

If you want `""` over `NA` do this next.

```
new[is.na(new)] <- ""

[1] "A" ""  "C"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
my_string[ !my_logical ] <- ""

my_string
# [1] "A" ""  "C"
```

Of course this overwrites existing object.